# Unzip or Untar a folder from S3 into the /tmp folder of an AWS Lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, zip, tar

I have a zip and a tar files added to AWS S3 bucket. The ZIp is actually a folder containing multiple files. I have a NodeJS Lambda function. I want to copy the compressed files from S3 to the /tmp folder then decompress them.

I was able to move the compressed files to the S3, however, I am unable to find a good library to decompress them.

Code:

```
    let params = { Bucket: "{BUCKET_NAME}", Key: "{key}.zip" };
    let data = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
    await fs.writeFile("/tmp/" + params.Key, data.Body, function (err2) {
    });
```

Comment: use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzipper

Comment: This is less related to AWS and is more of a Node.js question - even then, a quick google search can find you a multitude of libraries (: Unfortunately, most answers to this will likely be opinion-based, as opposed to fact-based, thus it doesn't make a particularly good Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Note that the tmp folder has limited memory and it can cause problems as your file sizes get bigger. You can read files into a buffer instead. If you are open to using Python to do the same, this will help you: https://betterprogramming.pub/unzip-and-gzip-incoming-s3-files-with-aws-lambda-f7bccf0099c9